# How to give forgot password link from home page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I have created a new template phtml file 2columns-right-home.phtml for home page of my Magento site. I want to give login form here. Also the links like 'create new account', 'Forgot Password', etc. How to give the links?

I tried the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>">Forgot password?</a>
```

But the page is not directing to the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `getUrl` function to get the link to the `forgotpassword` action for the `account` controller of the `customer` module (whose `frontName` happens to also be `customer`, [read more](http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world)). As so:

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>">Forgot password?</a>
```

[More info on `getUrl`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters)

Answer (score 2):

```
Mage::helper('customer')->getForgotPasswordUrl()
```

look at

```
var_dump(get_class_methods(get_class(Mage::helper('customer'))))
```

Answer (score -3):

Link For Forgot Password :

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>customer/account/forgotpassword">Forget Password ?</a>
```

Link for Account Create :

```
<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>customer/account/create">Create Account</a>
```

Comment: For this paticular case `getUrl` is definately best practice, let Magento do the work for you! What if, for example, Magento decide to change the way URL's work? Not likely, but at least by using core functionality unseen consequences can be avoided.